# PHP HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: php, http, iis, https

I am having difficulty with the header function in PHP.
The call to the function is initiated on a secure HTTPS page. Every time I call the header function with http://, something somewhere is changing the protocol to HTTPS.

In my program, this example:

```
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
```

takes me to https://www.google.com instead.

My environment is IIS 7.5 Windows 2008 64-Bit
PHP 5.5.12 with Fast CGI

Is there something that I have accidentally enabled either in IIS or php.ini that would automatically force http to https?

This does not happen when launching the code from an http page, http to http works, http to https works and https to https work. However, https to http is failing.

I've been searching and most results keep reversing my question by showing me ways to force http to https. I need the opposite.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

EDIT: Google was an example URL. Sorry.

```
header("Location: http://www.systronicsinc.com/");
```

is my actual URL that is failing. This keeps redirecting to https://www.systronicsinc.com/.

This is a raw header from Fiddler.

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Location: https://www.systronicsinc.com/
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.12
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=va1hh3ff8h0buus689kf86eoc1; path=/
Date: Fri, 24 Oct 2014 17:39:34 GMT
Content-Length: 156

<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="http://www.systronicsinc.com/">here</a></body>
```

I find it interesting that the link in the body retained the original http protocol as initially set, but the Location field in the header is modifying it to https. I've been hunting through IIS and my php.ini file. I cannot see anything that would dictate this behavior. Maybe this additional information will spark a thought with someone. Thanks!

Comment: are  you talking specifically about google? because google serves over https only and redirects if you try to http.

Comment: My apologies. Google was simply an example URL. I'm new to posting questions. Should I edit my question to use an alternate?

Comment: What do you have in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @Darren, I'm on a windows server running IIS 7.5. I don't have an .htaccess file.

Comment: Apologies, I completely over-looked that part !

Answer (score 0):

Google uses SSL, so https://, for it's websites.

See: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/173733?hl=en

and: https://www.seroundtable.com/google-ssl-drops-query-data-14188.html

Comment: I'm sorry. Google was an example URL. This happens on all URLs which causes errors for sites that do not employ SSL.

Comment: Ok, then please give a correct example. And test it in your code and browser, before you publish it.

Comment: Yes, better, but it also means I cannot explain it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, Google redirects you to a secure page.

They probably use a function that does something like my `https` function. Feel free to use.

```
function https(){
  $sv = $_SERVER;
  if(!isset($sv['HTTPS'])){
    header("LOCATION:https://{$sv['SERVER_NAME']}{$sv['PHP_SELF']}"); die;
  }
}
function http(){
  $sv = $_SERVER;
  if(isset($sv['HTTPS'])){
    unset($_SERVER['HTTPS']);
    header("LOCATION:http://{$sv['SERVER_NAME']}{$sv['PHP_SELF']}"); die;
  }
}
```

Comment: @PHPglue, I tried using unset($_SERVER['HTTPS']); and it did not seem to help.

Comment: You don't control their code. You're just redirecting your Clients to their `LOCATION`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've edited my question. Google was just an example URL, one that I will never use again. I gave another URL that doesn't have SSL, but the header() still changing http to https and making that request which fails since the site does not employ SSL.

Comment: I noticed that `Firefox` would hold onto the the `protocol` like `https`, even when I tried to go back to an insecure page. Try to force the `protocol` yourself with the functions I provided, and see if that works. If it still doesn't work it's some kind of configuration issue.

Comment: When your Browser locks on to a specific `protocol` like `https` it may stay in that mode force the `http()`.

Comment: I tried your code and I'm still being redirected to https. Even when I view the transport through Fiddler, I can see the actual Location header being set to https. This must be a configuration issue. I think I'll begin a hunt and peck through IIS tomorrow. :(

Comment: Well at least you know that much. I'm not a configuration expert.